# Unable to insert explicit value in table due to IDENTITY_INSERT is ON Error

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, insert, errors

I am trying to insert explicit values in one of my Real time Audit Production database. There are more than 80 columns, I have just taken here 5 columns.
I am writing syntax is as below:

```
use MyDatabaseName
go 

set identity_insert ObjectName.TableName on

insert into ObjectName.TableName ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5]) 
  values ('value1','value2','value3','value4','value5') 

set identity_insert ObjectName.TableName off
```

After executing the above T-SQL statement, I am getting below mention error:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
>   
> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'ObjectName.TableName' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I am `sysadmin` & `db_owner`. What is the problem?

Comment: Are any of the columns (i.e. `col1` through `col5`) an `IDENTITY` field? If not, then why are you using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`?

Comment: @srutzky, The First column is IDENTITY field. That's why using SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON.

Comment: So, in your example code in the Question, you are saying that `[col1]` is the `IDENTITY` field?

Comment: @srutzky ,yes you are right.

Comment: Are there any Triggers defined on this table that you are inserting into? Your syntax seems fine (outside of putting single-quotes around `'value1'`, but that can just be due it being simplistic example code).

Comment: Yes, check for triggers, also please confirm that `ObjectName.TableName` is exactly the same (the trigger could be trying to insert into a similarly named table, but not identical).

Comment: @srutzky,There is no any Triggers defined on this table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, ObjectName.TableName is exactly the same. I have also check out the column name in table, which column name i am taking in T-SQL that is same or not. That is also exactly the same name.

Comment: @AaronBertrand,There is Clustered "Indexes" defined on IDENTITY field of this table.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a new "fake" table? If col1 is the identity field, why are you inserting a string?